# If $n = km$ is a Descartes number with quasi-Euler prime $m$, then $m < k$.

Tags: inequality, proof-writing, solution-verification, divisor-sum, perfect-numbers

(Note:  This question is tangentially related to this [later one](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3609304).)

Let $$\sigma(x) = \sum_{d \mid x}{d}$$ denote the *sum of divisors* of $x \in \mathbb{N}$, where $\mathbb{N}$ is the set of natural numbers or positive integers.

Recall that a *Descartes number* is an odd number $n = km$, with $1 < k$, $1 < m$, satisfying $$\sigma(k)(m+1)=2km.$$  ($m$ is called the quasi-Euler prime of $n$.)  Note that we define $\sigma(m) := m + 1$ even when $m$ is composite (that is, we *pretend* that $m$ is prime).

Notice that the lone Descartes number that is known is
$$\mathscr{D} = k'm' = {{3003}^2}\cdot{22021}.$$

In particular, note that:

**(1)** $k$ is a square.

**(2)** $\sigma(k)/m = 2k - \sigma(k)$

**(3)** $m \equiv 1 \pmod 4$

I want to prove that it must necessarily be the case that $m < k$, for a Descartes number $n = km$.

**Lemma 1** If $n = km$ is a Descartes number with quasi-Euler prime $m$, then $k \neq m$.

To this end, suppose that $m = k$.  Then we have
$$\frac{\sigma(k)}{k} = \frac{2m}{m + 1} = \frac{2k}{k + 1},$$
from which it follows that
$$\sigma(k) = \frac{2k^2}{k + 1} = \frac{2k^2 - 2}{k + 1} + \frac{2}{k + 1} = \frac{2(k - 1)(k + 1)}{k + 1} + \frac{2}{k + 1} = 2(k - 1) + \frac{2}{k + 1}.$$

Since $\sigma(k)$ and $2(k - 1)$ are integers, it follows that $2/(k+1)$ is also an integer, which means that $(k + 1) \mid 2$.  This implies that $k + 1 \leq 2$, from which wet get $m = k \leq 1$.  This last inequality contradicts the condition $1 < k$, $1 < m$.

**Lemma 2** If $n = km$ is a Descartes number with quasi-Euler prime $m$ and $\gcd(m,k)=1$, then
$$\frac{\sigma(m)}{k} \neq \frac{\sigma(k)}{m}.$$

Suppose to the contrary that $n = km$ is a Descartes number with quasi-Euler prime $m$ and $\gcd(m,k)=1$, and that $\sigma(m)/k = \sigma(k)/m$.  Then it follows that
$$\frac{\sigma(m)}{k} = \frac{\sigma(k)}{m} = r \in \mathbb{N},$$
from which we obtain
$$\frac{\sigma(m)}{k}\cdot\frac{\sigma(k)}{m} = r^2 \in \mathbb{N},$$
contradicting
$$\sigma(k)\sigma(m) = \sigma(k)(m+1) = 2km,$$
since the last two equations imply that $r^2 = 2$.

**Lemma 3** If $n = km$ is a Descartes number with quasi-Euler prime $m$ and $\gcd(m, k) = 1$, then we have

**(a)** $\sigma(m) \neq \sigma(k)$

**(b)** $\sigma(m) \neq k$

**(c)** $\sigma(k) \neq m$

Proof of **(a)**:  Suppose that $\sigma(k) = \sigma(m) = m + 1 \equiv 2 \pmod 4$.  This contradicts the fact that $k$ is a square, since then $\sigma(k) \equiv 1 \pmod 2$.

Proof of **(b)**:  Suppose that $\sigma(m) = k$.  Then the even number $m + 1 = \sigma(m)$ is equal to the odd number $k$, which is a clear contradiction.

Proof of **(c)**:  Suppose to the contrary that $\sigma(k) = m$.  Then we obtain the estimate
$$\frac{\sigma(k)}{m} + \frac{\sigma(m)}{k} = 1 + 2 = 3,$$
which contradicts the known quantity
$$\frac{\sigma(k')}{m'} + \frac{\sigma(m')}{k'} = \frac{670763}{819} \approx 819.002.$$

**Lemma 4** If $n = km$ is a Descartes number with quasi-Euler prime $m$ and $\gcd(m, k)=1$, then the following biconditionals hold:
$$m < k \iff \sigma(m) < \sigma(k) \iff \frac{\sigma(m)}{k} < \frac{\sigma(k)}{m}$$

We consider three different cases:

**Case (1)**:
$$\frac{\sigma(m)}{k} + \frac{\sigma(k)}{m} = \frac{\sigma(m)}{m} + \frac{\sigma(k)}{k}$$

Case (1) is equivalent to $\sigma(m) = \sigma(k)$ (which is ruled out by Lemma 3 (a)) or $k = m$ (which is ruled out by Lemma 1).

**Case (2)**:
$$\frac{\sigma(m)}{k} + \frac{\sigma(k)}{m} < \frac{\sigma(m)}{m} + \frac{\sigma(k)}{k}$$

Case (2) implies the estimate
$$\frac{\sigma(m)}{k} + \frac{\sigma(k)}{m} < \frac{\sigma(m)}{m} + \frac{\sigma(k)}{k} < \frac{9 + 1}{9} + 2 = \frac{28}{9},$$
which again contradicts the known quantity
$$\frac{\sigma(k')}{m'} + \frac{\sigma(m')}{k'} = \frac{670763}{819} \approx 819.002.$$

**Case (3)**:
$$\frac{\sigma(m)}{m} + \frac{\sigma(k)}{k} < \frac{\sigma(m)}{k} + \frac{\sigma(k)}{m}$$

Case (3) is equivalent to the truth of the biconditional $m < k \iff \sigma(m) < \sigma(k)$ (by virtue of Lemma 1, Lemma 2, and Lemma 3), which in turn is equivalent to the truth of the biconditional
$$m < k \iff \sigma(m) < \sigma(k) \iff \frac{\sigma(m)}{k} < \frac{\sigma(k)}{m}.$$

By Lemma 4, we have the following possibilities:

**(A)** $k < \sigma(k) < m < \sigma(m)$

**(B)** $m < \sigma(m) < k < \sigma(k)$

Note that Case **(A)** implies that
$$\frac{\sigma(k)}{m} = 2k - \sigma(k) < 1$$
forcing $2k - \sigma(k) = 0$ (i.e. $k$ must be perfect).  This contradicts the fact that $k$ is a square.

Hence we necessarily have Case **(B)**, and a proof for the following theorem:

**THEOREM** If $n = km$ is a Descartes number with quasi-Euler prime $m$ and $\gcd(m, k) = 1$, then $k$ is *not* an odd almost perfect number.

**QUESTIONS**

*(I)* Can we remove the reliance of the proof on the condition
$$\frac{\sigma(k')}{m'} + \frac{\sigma(m')}{k'} = \frac{670763}{819} \approx 819.002?$$

*(II)* To what extent can we relax the condition $\gcd(m, k)=1$ in the **THEOREM**?

Comment: Note that all we need is a proof for the condition
$$\frac{\sigma(k)}{m} = 2k - \sigma(k) \geq 3,$$
an analogue of a problem which was considered for the case of odd perfect numbers in [Dris, 2008 (page 108)](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1204.1450v2.pdf).

Comment: Additionally, we can consider whether the following *Conjecture* holds:

"**Conjecture**:  If $n = km$ is a Descartes number with quasi-Euler prime $m$ and $\gcd(m, k)=1$, then $\sqrt{k} < m$."

The truth of this *Conjecture* will imply that the quasi-Euler prime $m$ is the largest prime factor of the Descartes number $n$.

Comment: Your question is rather long; I stopped reading when I read
$$\text{"I want to prove that it must necessarily be the case that $m<k$, for a Descartes number $n=mk$."},$$
because I saw a straightforward proof, and there was a lot of technical stuff coming that I didn't want to work my way through. If my answer doesn't apply to your question, please let me know.

Comment: @Servaes:  Please do not delete your answer because I think it is very much correct (and an unconditional proof, at that!).  I will let the bounty stand for now (so that the question, and your answer, may attract more attention/votes).  Thank you for your time and attention.

Comment: There is a minor mistake, which I do believe can be fixed. But I will leave my answer deleted until it is fixed.

Comment: Okay, looking forward to seeing your revised/updated answer, @Servaes!  =)

Comment: The problem is 'fixed', but the result is rather disappointing now; the condition that $m<k$ is equivalent to $k$ not being almost perfect. The existence of odd almost perfect numbers greater than $1$ is an open problem, to my knowledge.

Comment: Ahh yes, I am already aware of that.  This is because I know that a number $N \geq 1$ is almost perfect if and only if
$$\frac{2N}{N+1} \leq \frac{\sigma(N)}{N} < 2.$$

Comment: Ok, so you are aware of the fact that you have just put a 500 rep bounty on a question asking
$$\text{Prove that $1$ is the only odd almost perfect number.}$$
That's quite a challenge, I would say, given the current literature on that exact problem.

Comment: @Servaes, I would not be so blunt as to put it that way.  You see, there have been some progress along these lines (albeit, published in an unreputable journal).  Please see [article1](https://ijntindia.puzl.com/files/1638779/download/2_dris-spoof_13-26.pdf) and [article2](https://ijntindia.puzl.com/files/1670557/download/dristejada.pdf).  This is also the main reason for this question, and hence, the bounty.  Note that this question was originally asked in April of 2018.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a partial answer.

*(II)* : I think that we can prove $m\lt k$ without assuming that $\gcd(k,m)=1$.

---

(1) Your proof for Lemma 1 is correct.

(2) We can prove $\frac{\sigma(m)}{k} \neq \frac{\sigma(k)}{m}$ without assuming $\gcd(k,m)=1$.

Supposing that $\sigma(m)/k = \sigma(k)/m$ gives 
$$\frac{m+1}{k}= \frac{2k}{m+1}\implies \bigg(\frac{m+1}{k}\bigg)^2=2\implies \frac{m+1}{k}=\sqrt 2$$
which is a contradiction since LHS is rational while RHS isn't.

(3) You can prove **(a)** $\sigma(m) \neq \sigma(k)$ **(b)** $\sigma(m) \neq k$  **(c)** $\sigma(k) \neq m$ without assuming $\gcd(k,m)=1$ since you haven't used $\gcd(k,m)=1$ in your proof for Lemma 3.

(4) Lemma 4 is true without assuming $\gcd(k,m)=1$. The proof for $m\lt k\iff \sigma(m)\lt\sigma(k)$ is written in the question. The proof for $m\lt k\iff\frac{\sigma(m)}{k}\lt \frac{\sigma(m)}{k}$ is written in the comments below.

(5) In **(A)**, another way to get a contradiction : We have $0\lt 2k-\sigma(k)\lt 1$ which contradicts that $2k-\sigma(k)$ is an integer.

---

In conclusion, we can prove $m\lt k$ without assuming that $\gcd(k,m)=1$.

(Moreover, I think that you can prove $m\lt k$ without using Lemma 2.)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, @mathlove.  Perhaps I was not clear enough.
$$\mathscr{D} = {{3003}^2}\cdot{22021}$$
is a Descartes number, and so
$$\sigma(m') = m' + 1 = 22021 + 1 = 22022.$$
The WolframAlpha computational verification is [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28DivisorSigma%5B1%2C9018009%5D%2F22021%29%2B%2822022%2F9018009%29).

Comment: Additionally, can you please clarify further how you were able to prove
$$m < k \iff \sigma(m) < \sigma(k)?$$
Lastly, would you mind shooting me an e-mail, @mathlove?  It is josearnaldobdris AT gmail DOT com.

Comment: I do confirm that your proof for **Lemma 2** (without the condition $\gcd(m,k)=1$) is correct.

Comment: An upvote for now.  +1!  =)

Comment: @Jose Arnaldo Bebita-Dris: You are right. I forgot $\sigma(m')=m'+1$ in the example. I've deleted it. To your second comment, I think you have proved $m\lt k\iff \sigma(m)\lt\sigma(k)$ without using $\gcd(k,m)=1$. Do you still want me to clarify how?

Comment: Ahh, yes indeed @mathlove.  My apologies for the oversight.  No need to clarify.  =)

Comment: I will let the bounty stand for now (so that the question, and your answer) gets to attract more votes (hopefully!).  So just to clarify:  We still could not remove the reliance of the proof on the condition
$$\frac{\sigma(k')}{m'}+\frac{\sigma(m')}{k'}=\frac{670763}{819} \approx 819.002?$$
Thanks again!

Comment: @Jose Arnaldo Bebita-Dris: You are right. I cannot remove the reliance.

Comment: @Jose Arnaldo Bebita-Dris : So, we are in the situation where we know that $m\lt k$ is true without assuming that $\gcd(k,m)=1$, but with the reliance of the proof on the condition. Is my understanding correct? If this is correct, I'll try to remove the reliance.

Comment: Yes, currently the proof is already independent of the condition $\gcd(k,m)=1$.  It remains to remove the reliance of the proof on the last condition.

Comment: I just have a quick comment regarding the truth of the biconditional
$$\frac{\sigma(m)}{k} < \frac{\sigma(k)}{m} \iff m < k.$$
Since $m$ is the quasi-Euler prime, $m \equiv 1 \pmod 4$ and $m$ is composite, which implies that $m \geq 9$.  We obtain
$$\frac{\sigma(m)}{m} \leq \frac{10}{9} < \frac{9}{5} \leq \frac{\sigma(k)}{k}.$$
Thus, if we could prove that $m < k \iff \sigma(m) < \sigma(k)$ indeed holds, then we have
$$\frac{\sigma(m)}{m} < \frac{\sigma(k)}{k} \land \frac{\sigma(m)}{k} < \frac{\sigma(k)}{m} \implies \sigma(m) < \sigma(k) \iff m < k \iff \frac{1}{k} < \frac{1}{m} \iff$$

Comment: Thus,
$$\frac{\sigma(m)}{k} < \frac{\sigma(k)}{m} \implies \sigma(m) < \sigma(k) \iff m < k \iff \frac{1}{k} < \frac{1}{m} \implies \frac{\sigma(m)}{k} < \frac{\sigma(k)}{m}$$
holds, so that the biconditional
$$\frac{\sigma(m)}{k} < \frac{\sigma(k)}{m} \iff \bigg(\sigma(m) < \sigma(k) \iff m < k\bigg)$$
holds.

Comment: Please let me know if my last two comments make sense to you, @mathlove.

Comment: I meant to say
$$, \ldots \text{ so that the biconditional } \frac{\sigma(m)}{k} < \frac{\sigma(k)}{m} \iff \sigma(m) < \sigma(k)$$
and therefore, the biconditional
$$\frac{\sigma(m)}{k} < \frac{\sigma(k)}{m} \iff m < k$$
also holds, @mathlove.

Comment: @Jose Arnaldo Bebita-Dris : I've found no errors. Nicely done!

Comment: Thank you for the confirmation, @mathlove!  =)

Comment: I suggest you edit your answer to reflect these recent findings regarding **Lemma 4**, @mathlove.  =)

Comment: @Jose Arnaldo Bebita-Dris : I've just edited my answer to reflect them.

Comment: Thanks again, @mathlove!  =)

Answer (score 1):

Let $k$ and $m$ be odd integers greater than $1$ such that
$$(m+1)\sigma(k)=2mk.$$
Then clearly $\sigma(k)<2k$, and hence the above is equivalent to
$$m=\frac{\sigma(k)}{2k-\sigma(k)}.$$
Now the desired result that $m<k$ is equivalent to
$$\frac{\sigma(k)}{2k-\sigma(k)}<k,$$
which in turn, by clearing denominators and rearranging, is equivalent to
$$\sigma(k)<\frac{2k^2}{k+1}=2k-2+\frac{2}{k+1}.$$
In particular, as $k>1$ this is equivalent to
$$\sigma(k)\leq 2k-2.$$
As we already saw that $\sigma(k)<2k$, this is equivalent to $\sigma(k)\neq2k-1$.

So your desired result that $m<k$ is equivalent to $k$ *not* being an odd almost perfect number. Whether any odd almost perfect number greater than $1$ exists is an open problem, to my knowledge.

Put differently; the (integral) solutions to
$$(m+1)\sigma(k)=2mk,$$
with $k$ and $m$ both odd that do *not* satisfy $m<k$, are precisely the pairs
$$(k,m)=\left(k,\sigma(k)\right),$$
where $k$ is an almost perfect number. In particular $k$ is a perfect square.

Comment: Nice, but it seems that the OP has already known that. See [the OP's answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3570437/78967).

Comment: @mathlove Thank you for the reference; as you may know this rather disappointing conclusion came from a correction to my original answer. A silly $\pm$-error gave me the conclusion that $m<k$ holds unconditionally.

Comment: I think that, from the inequality
$$\sigma(k) < \frac{2k^2}{k+1} = 2k - 2 + \frac{2}{k+1},$$
we can directly get, from $k>1$,
$$\frac{2}{k+1} < 1$$
so that we have the chain of inequalities
$$\sigma(k) < \frac{2k^2}{k+1} < (2k - 2) + 1 = 2k - 1.$$

Comment: @JoseArnaldoBebita-Dris Yes; that is precisely what I meant by
$$\text{In particular, as $k>1$ this is equivalent to}\hspace{100pt}$$
$$\sigma(k)\leq 2k-2.$$

Comment: Rewriting
$$m = \frac{\sigma(k)}{2k - \sigma(k)}$$
as
$$m = \frac{\sigma(k) - 2k}{2k - \sigma(k)} + \frac{2k}{2k - \sigma(k)} = -1 + 2\cdot\bigg(\frac{k}{2k - \sigma(k)}\bigg),$$
and noting that $2k - \sigma(k)$ is odd (since $k$ is a square), then we get the additional condition that
$$(2k - \sigma(k)) \mid k.$$
In other words, $k$ is [deficient-perfect](http://oeis.org/A271816).  This also follows from the fact that $k$ is almost perfect, since then
$$\sigma(k) = 2k - 1 \iff 2k - \sigma(k) = 1 \mid k \hspace{5pt} \forall k.$$

Comment: The ideas in this [MSE question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3096039) (and the answers contained therein) may thenceforth be applicable.

Answer (score 0):

(This is not an answer - just some comments that are too long to fit in the appropriate section.)

Note that the inequality $m < k$ is equivalent to the assertion "$k$ is not an odd almost perfect number", where $n = km$ is a Descartes number with quasi-Euler prime $m$.

This is proved in the paper "The Non-Euler Part of a Spoof Odd Perfect Number is not Almost Perfect", which is joint work between Dris and Tejada, and published in the [Indian Journal in Number Theory](https://ijntindia.puzl.com/archives).