# Can these bounds in terms of the abundancy index and deficiency functions be improved for deficient-perfect numbers?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, upper-lower-bounds, divisor-sum, perfect-numbers

Let
$$\sigma(x) = \sum_{e \mid x}{e}$$
denote the *sum of divisors* of the positive integer $x$.  Denote the *abundancy index* of $x$ by $I(x)=\sigma(x)/x$, and the *deficiency* of $x$ by $D(x)=2x-\sigma(x)$.  A positive integer $N$ is said to be *deficient-perfect* if $D(N) \mid N$.

Here is my question:

> Can these bounds in terms of the abundancy index and deficiency functions be improved for *deficient-perfect numbers* $N > 1$?
>   $$\frac{2N}{N + D(N)} < I(N) < \frac{2N + D(N)}{N + D(N)}$$

(Note that the inequality
$$\frac{2N}{N + D(N)} < I(N) < \frac{2N + D(N)}{N + D(N)}$$
is true if and only if $N$ is deficient.)

**References**

[A Criterion for Deficient Numbers Using the Abundancy Index and Deficiency Functions, Journal for Algebra and Number Theory Academia, Volume 8, Issue 1, February 2018, pages 1-9](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1308.6767.pdf)

Comment: Which result does the paper prove ? Maybe, it can be used to prove your stronger statement.

Comment: @Peter:  The paper proves the inequality above, giving a criterion for deficient numbers in terms of the abundancy index and deficiency functions.  I am currently trying to determine whether the inequality above could be improved to account for the case when $N > 1$ is deficient-perfect.

Comment: Perhaps one can use the fact that $$D(N) = 2N - \sigma(N) = \gcd(N, \sigma(N))$$
which holds when $N$ is deficient-perfect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose that $N > 1$ is deficient-perfect.  Since $N$ is deficient, then
$$\frac{2N}{N + D(N)} < I(N) < \frac{2N + D(N)}{N + D(N)}.$$

I think that, since $D(N) \mid N$ when $N$ is deficient-perfect, then $N/D(N)$ is an integer, so that we have (since $\frac{N}{D(N)} \mid N$)
$$I\bigg(\frac{N}{D(N)}\bigg) \leq I(N) < \frac{2N + D(N)}{N + D(N)} = \frac{2\bigg(\frac{N}{D(N)}\bigg) + 1}{\bigg(\frac{N}{D(N)}\bigg) + 1}.$$

**CLAIM**

$$\frac{2\bigg(\frac{N}{D(N)}\bigg)}{\bigg(\frac{N}{D(N)}\bigg) + 1} < I\bigg(\frac{N}{D(N)}\bigg)$$

*This claim, if true, would prove that all deficient-perfect numbers $N$ correspond to almost perfect numbers $N/D(N)$.*

**Added April 18 2019 (6:13 PM - Manila time)**

The claim is false.  A counterexample is given by $$N = \bigg({3}\cdot{7}\cdot{11}\cdot{13}\bigg)^2.$$

**Added April 18 2019 (6:17 PM - Manila time)**

It appears that the claim is true when $D(N)=1$.

Answer (score 0):

**ILLUSTRATING VIA A TOY EXAMPLE**

Let $M$ be an odd perfect number given in the so-called Eulerian form
$$M = p^k m^2$$
(i.e. $p$ is the special prime satisfying $p \equiv k \equiv 1 \pmod 4$ and $\gcd(p,m)=1$).

It is known that the non-Euler part $m^2$ is deficient-perfect if and only if the Descartes-Frenicle-Sorli conjecture that $k=1$ holds.  (See this [paper](http://nntdm.net/papers/nntdm-23/NNTDM-23-2-012-020.pdf) for a proof of this fact.)

So, suppose that $k=1$.  Then $m^2$ is deficient-perfect.

In particular, $m^2$ *is* deficient, so that the criterion in this [paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1308.6767.pdf) applies.

We have
$$\frac{2m^2}{m^2 + D(m^2)} < I(m^2) < \frac{2m^2 + D(m^2)}{m^2 + D(m^2)}.$$

Under the hypothesis that $k=1$, $m^2$ is deficient-perfect, with deficiency 
$$D(m^2) = \frac{m^2}{(p+1)/2}.$$

We also have
$$I(m^2) = \frac{2}{I(p)} = \frac{2p}{p+1}.$$

Putting these all together, we have
$$\frac{m^2}{D(m^2)} = \frac{p+1}{2}$$
$$\frac{2p}{p+1} = I(m^2) > \frac{2m^2}{m^2 + D(m^2)} = \frac{2\bigg(\frac{m^2}{D(m^2)}\bigg)}{\frac{m^2}{D(m^2)} + 1} = \frac{2\bigg(\frac{p+1}{2}\bigg)}{\bigg(\frac{p+1}{2}\bigg) + 1} = \frac{p+1}{\frac{p+3}{2}} = \frac{2(p+1)}{p+3}$$
which implies that
$$p^2 + 3p = p(p+3) > (p+1)^2 = p^2 + 2p + 1$$
$$p > 1$$
(This last inequality is trivial as $p$ is prime with $p \equiv 1 \pmod 4$ implies that $p \geq 5$.)
$$\frac{2p}{p+1} = I(m^2) < \frac{2m^2 + D(m^2)}{m^2 + D(m^2)} = \frac{2\bigg(\frac{m^2}{D(m^2)}\bigg) + 1}{\frac{m^2}{D(m^2)} + 1} = \frac{2\bigg(\frac{p+1}{2}\bigg) + 1}{\bigg(\frac{p+1}{2}\bigg) + 1} = \frac{p+2}{\frac{p+3}{2}} = \frac{2(p+2)}{p+3}$$
which implies that
$$p^2 + 3p = p(p+3) < (p+1)(p+2) = p^2 + 3p + 2$$
$$0 < 2.$$

*This example illustrates my interest in improvements to the bounds in terms of the abundancy index and deficiency functions of $N$, when $N > 1$ is deficient-perfect.*